# Boinc not working

Tags: 12.04, boinc

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 last week and Boinc stopped running instantly.  I understand that there is a problem with Boinc and 12.04 -- there seems to be finger pointing in both directions at this point in time.  It seems that Boinc is working on a 7.0.27 release and that bug reports have been registered with Launchpad.  Not sure where response should be coming from  ~~~~~ Boinc still not working!

By the way - I use "seti@home" as my project.  7.0.25 is my current Boinc install.

Comment: I've found that most projects do not work at all, exiting with computation errors, but on my 12.04 system, the following projects are working: AlmereGrid, Correlizer, Leiden Classical, NFS@home, NRG, and SubsetSum@home. You might consider trying one or more of these until SETI@home works again.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen 7.0.24 was the buggy version, causing "computation error" on every Project that uses the Charmm application for its Tasks. I ran

$ **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pkg-boinc/testing**

to add the BOINC/testing PPA so I could try 7.0.27 in PP 12.04, and it has not given me 'computation error' on Charmm app work units since.

I would expect 7.0.27 to be available from the regular repository soon, if it's not already (I'm on an old fedora machine at the moment), without having to enable the boinc/testing PPA, so fire up Synaptic or whatever package frontend you use and see if it's there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Boinc 7.0.27 is already available in Software Center for Precise 12.04 onwards. I've just downloaded it and it works correctly for both Seti@Home and Einstein@Home, so I guess this problem was (finally!) solved :)